# Identifying voice as male or female

Tags: php, audio, artificial-intelligence, voice

I'm not much into audio engineering, so please be easy on me. I'm receiving an audio file as input, and need to detect whether the speaker is male or female. Any ideas how to go about doing this?

I'm using php, but am open to using other languages, and don't mind learning a little bit of sound theory as long as the time is proportionate to the task.

Comment: Is it good enough to identify whether the *frequency* of the voice is statistically **more probable** to be male or female?  Otherwise, you might be stuck playing the **Imitation Game:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_Game#Versions_of_the_Turing_test

Comment: @Mark, If you say it it, I'll take your word for it

Comment: Be careful using information you get from this in a live interaction.  People can get fairly hostile if they think you've identified their gender wrong.  If you intend to, keep it very subtle.  Pushing very gender specific sales pitches or using "sir/madam" is going to cost you far more than you're likely to get out of it.

Comment: I suggest you take sound clips of two people (one male, one female) speaking out sentences in the same tone. Load it up into an audio program and look for visual distinctions between the pitch and fluctuation of the two clips. Of course, this is only a small sample, but it should get you started. Things like these really need to build upon data over time in order to achieve fairly accurate results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't really provide specific insight to this problem , but I'd start by reading the following article: [Gender Classification from Speech](http://www.projapps.com/CS5240.doc).

That should at least give an idea of the concepts / methodologies involved (this article describes this quite well as far as I can tell).

Comment: Also worth mentioning is LIUM spkdiarization, see my post  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010215/478237

Answer (score 3):

First of all you will have to find pitch values and one great algorithm for finding pitch values for voice can be find on this article: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/paul/papers/Proceedings_1993.pdf .

It's amazingly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Christophe, both in that I don't have too much experience with this and also think some research would be your best path.

If I had to take a stab at this though, I would guess that it would involve computing the frequency spectrum of the sample using Fourier transforms, and then figuring out where the mean frequency lay.  Build up a large sample of male vs female, for different cultures and languages, and then compare your specific sample's mean frequency to established means for male vs female.

I could be completely wrong though, so research is really your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use artificial neural networks.  You provide the neural net with some examples for training and it should hopefully learn to correctly classify the voices.  You will probably have to do some feature extraction using Fourier transforms to get the data into a suitable form.

There are several papers about this kind of approach if you search on Google for "neural network speaker identification" but unfortunately I am not familiar enough with them to recommend any particular one.